# Python do action without pop up response

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter, popup

I've been trying to write a python program to automatically shut down my computer. The Notification Messagebox module uses tkinter code like in [TutorialPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/tk_messagebox.htm). The pop up will show Yes / No options.
with the current code, only if i press "*No*" button, the system will shutdown.

So instead, it should automatically start the shutdown process without me clicking anything. At the sametime, if i click "Yes", then the shutdown process should stop.

This is the code. How do i accomplish this?

```
import MessageBox
def PopUp(Title, Msg, Type='Info'):
    Title = str(Title)
    Msg = str(Msg)

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    if Type == "Question":
        response = MessageBox.askquestion(Title, Msg)
        print("question", response)
        return response
    elif Type == "TryAgain":
        response = MessageBox.askretrycancel(Title, Msg)
        print("try again", response)
        return response
    else:
        print("Incorrect Type selected.")
        response = MessageBox.showinfo(Title, Msg)
        print("info", response)
        return response

def main():
    CurrentTime = int(time.strftime('%H'))
    if CurrentTime > 22 or CurrentTime < 5:
        msg = ("The Time is %s hours. Abort Automatic Shutdown?" % CurrentTime)
        resp1 = Notification.PopUp("Auto Shut Down", msg, Type="Question")
        print('Response from Notification is %s' % resp1)

        if resp1 == 'no':
            closeApps()
            shutDown()
        else:
            print('ShutDown abortered by user.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `closeApps()`, you could use `psutil` module,

```
import psutil
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.name()=="Application.exe":
        process.kill()
```

The `psutil.process_iter()` gives a list of all running processes.

Note: Replace `"Application.exe"` with the name of the application to close.

As for `shutDown()`, you simply have to use `os` to give terminal commands:

```
import os
os.system("shutdown /s")
```

Comment: Thanks. I already have a function for both CloseApps() and ShutDown() but my problem is that the Shutdown should start automatically but if i want to abort, I should still be able to...

Comment: The terminal command `shutdown /a` can be used to abort shutdown. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358929/prevent-windows-7-shutdown